# Angular performance - filtering large data set

Tags: performance, angularjs, checkbox, filtering

I've asked this question on the Angular forums but hoping for more input here
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/-TIYs_vfs74

We have a large data set, potentially several thousand results, though just currently a maximum of about 500. We have paging, ordering and filtering (powered by checkboxes). We have noticed that there is an ever so slight delay between selecting the checkbox and/or checkbox label and the dataset being updated. It is a minor delay, very minor and noticed it after looking at some large sites that use clientside filtering, such as SkyScanner:
http://www.skyscanner.net/transport/flights/lond/nyca/140513/140531/airfares-from-london-to-new-york-in-may-2014.html?rtn=1
Their checkboxes are rapid. Ours have no more than a second delay.

Unfortunately I can't share our site (though anyone wishing to take a closer look, please get in touch) but I have mocked up a demo
http://plnkr.co/edit/HWDtfmUzWcrqux762Fmu?p=preview

Typically this works very quickly (even locally with 2000 results) so it has me thinking that other JS in our app is causing the slow down. So that's something to look at.

However the main reason I come here is to get a sanity check on our filtering approach. Is it correct? Is it scalable? Any issues you see? In the plunker demo, in script.js, there is a commented-out console.log on line 33. If you enable that it will run the console 600 times, exactly three times the amount of results in the dataset.

SkyScanner uses Backbone and therefore I wonder whether it then uses Underscore. Is Underscore going to be a benefit to our project?

Generally, any thoughts, tips, solutions you have, please say :)

One of the potential solutions on the other forum was to use an approach similar to http://plnkr.co/edit/zhEjU2pwM0MlrGWpTEDH?p=preview
From what I can tell that flattens each result into a string and then searches the string. How will that perform with 2k+ results?

Cheers
Tom

Comment: Usually pagination goes till server side, you don't load a whole dataset and then filter and paginate on client side.

Comment: Thanks Florian. I thought the filtering and pagination was at the very heart of Angular and indeed the whole point of it? So it's all client side.

Comment: It is, but you should implement a filter object which contains whichever filter and pagination information you need and send it to your backend whenever you change page (page as in pagination), via a RESTful service (using $resource) by instance. The point of angular in this case is just that when you get the answer from backend, you just have to bind the array of objects to your scope var and your table or whatever representation you're using updates itself.

Comment: Thanks. In this app we are only looking to hit the service once, to get all the data in the first place, and then provide client-side only filtering.

Comment: See the SkyScanner example which is all clientside and very fast filtering
http://www.skyscanner.net/transport/flights/lond/nyca/140513/140531/airfares-from-london-to-new-york-in-may-2014.html?rtn=1

Comment: Javascript is so fast these days that filtering a few thousand records should be unnoticeable. I would set the bar where it might get problematic much higher. I suggest you use a profiler (e.g. chrome devtools) to show you where the time is going.